# jQuery combine two tr class into one

Tags: jquery, html-table

Sorry just got an update, the tr class A and B are repeating a lot. I want to combine each AB into C and show all the Cs.

I got a table like this:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr class="A">
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td>
<td>33333</td>    
</tr>
<tr class="B">
<td>44444</td>
<td>55555</td>
<td>66666</td>    
</tr>
<tr class="A">
<td>77777</td>
<td>88888</td>
<td>99999</td>    
</tr>
<tr class="B">
<td>10101</td>
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td>    
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is some jQuery to combine the two tr together like:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr class="C">
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td>
<td>33333</td>    
<td>44444</td>
<td>55555</td>
<td>66666</td>    
</tr>
<tr class="C">
<td>77777</td>
<td>88888</td>
<td>99999</td>    
<td>10101</td>
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td>    
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/65XaF/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $('.A');
    var b = $('.B');
    a
        .append(b.children())
        .removeClass('A')
        .addClass('C');
    b.remove();
});​
```

Note: question was updated to reflect multiple A & B groups after this answer.

Comment: It seems that these are the only classes, so I would just make one call to `.prop('class', 'C')`.

Comment: Hi Joseph, actually there are lost A and B classes... What i want at the end is all the C classes....

Comment: @Simpledog - Not following you. That's exactly what I'm proposing: http://jsfiddle.net/65XaF/4/

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the first table and insert the data into a second you could do something like this:

```
var c = $('.C');

c.append($('.A').children().clone());
c.append($('.B').children().clone());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mA88C/

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
$('.A,.B').remove().children('td').appendTo($('<tr />', {'class':'C'})
                                  .appendTo('table'));​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/szfrd/2/)

Since the question just changed to include multiple occurences of the same classes, a modified version that will work with the new HTML in the question:

```
$('.A').each(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).next('.B')).remove().children('td')
           .appendTo($('<tr />', {'class':'C'})
           .appendTo('table'));
});
```

​[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/szfrd/3/)

or a little more like what Joseph Silber is suggesting:

```
$('.A').each(function() {
    $(this).append($(this).next('.B').remove().children()).prop('class','C');
});
```

Comment: Hi Adeneo, thank you but it seems like put all the As and Bs into one C class... What I need is each A and B combine into C so end up with all the tr in C class.

Comment: @Simpledog - added that to my answer aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more performant one-liner:

```
$('.A').prop('class', 'C').append( $('.B').remove().children() );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dAJ4L/

---

If you have multiples, use this:

```
$('.A').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('class', 'C').append( $(this).next().remove().children() );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bMHNv/

---

...and if you can get over the obsession for one-liners, you should cache `$(this)`:

```
$('.A').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prop('class', 'C').append( $this.next().remove().children() );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bMHNv/1/

---

**P.S.** Any interaction with the DOM is extremely expensive. When manipulating a big set of data, it is recommended that you first detach the elements from the DOM, do your manipulation, then add it back in. So, for performance nirvana, you should [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) your table from the DOM before manipulating it:

```
var $table = $('.table').detach();

$table.find('.A').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prop('class', 'C').append( $this.next().remove().children() );
});

// Insert the table back into the DOM.
// Since I don't know your DOM structure, I can't help you out with this.
// You'll have to figure it out on your own.
```

And finally, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bMHNv/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

```
var allTds = $('.table > tbody > tr > td');  // Get all the TD's
$("tbody").html("<tr class='C'></tr>");      // Add the TR C Class
$(".C").html(allTds);                        // Add the TD's
```